# Autoomatically adding date counters

Tags: sas

I have a dataset where I want to automatically add date counters. The following is the output I want where I am given the Type column.

```
Type  Date
A    Jan2001
A    Feb2001
A    Mar2001
B    Jan2001
B    Feb2001
B    Mar2001
```

And this is my psudocode:

```
data stub; 
 set data;
 if first.type then date = "Jan2001;
  data = date + month;
 run;
```

How do you go about doing this?

Comment: What do you want?  Show the final dataset.

Comment: I want to add dates for each type

Comment: You want what you show in the first code block?  Or you want something else?

Comment: Yes. The code block is just my pseudocode. I am not sure how to translate that into SAS code. I want the date to update for records within the same type and then start over for a new type.

Comment: No, that's the second code block.  The first code block, with Type and Date, that's what you have already, or what you want?

Comment: Sorry. What I want. Thats the output I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.  INTNX increments by a period.

```
data stub;
set yourdata;
retain datecounter;
by type;
if first.type then datecounter='01JAN2001'd;
else datecounter=intnx('Month',datecounter,1);
format datecounter DATE9.;
run;
```